# Related Record Action Items Hide/Remove

Tags: page-layout

Is it possible to hide a particular action from the Related Record Standard Component. I am trying to use it on LEX pages. The OWD settings are private for the Object.
Observation: In related record component if i click on remove it just removing the lightning card and not actually deleting the related record associated with the Parent (lookup). I understand other option is to code custom component.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These buttons are standard and driven by Read/Edit access on fields. Removing FLS (edit) from related fields , removed the 'Remove' Button.